# Ubuntu 16.04 and AMD RADEON HD 6750: The system is running in low-graphics mode

Tags: 16.04, graphics, fglrx, amd-graphics

I'd like to install Ubuntu 16.04 on desktop with AMD video card but after successfull install and reboot I got black screen with popap "The system is running in low-graphics mode".

After some investigation I found out that the deal is something about right drivers graphics card.

```
sudo dpkg -l fglrx fglrx-cre fglrx-amdcccle fglrx fglrx-dev
```

result: no packages found matching fglrx*
but when

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

result: Package **fglrx** i not available, but is reffered to by another package
E: Package 'fglrx' has no installation candidates.

Is there a fix to install Ubuntu 16.04 with AMD? I wasn't able to find a proper driver fo Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

On Sunday, I decided to upgrade to 16.04. And have a similar problem.
I did as it is written here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321874&p=13515588#post13515588 . Radeon R9 390x works fine.

---

1. Download crimson drivers from amd site http://support.amd.com/en-us/download.
2. Then unpack it.

   ```
   sh amd-driver-installer-15.302-x86.x86_64.run --extract
   cd fglrx-install. * /
   ```
3. And patch

   ```
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/im...ernel_4.4.diff
   patch -p1 <fglrx_kernel_4.4.diff
   ```
4. Downgrade xserver-xorg to 1.17. remove current xserver package

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg*
   ```
5. Commented out the current repository.

   ```
   sudo sed -i 's / deb / # deb /' /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
6. Add wily repository in the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

   ```
   deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main  
   deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily-updates main
   ```
7. Install the xserver from wily repository.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update  
   sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg
   ```
8. Hold packages with reduced version xserver.

   ```
   packages = `aptitude search xserver | grep -E '^ i' | grep -Eo '(. xserver - +) -' | awk '{print $ 1}'`; for pkg in $ packages; do echo "$pkg hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections; done
   ```
9. Restore the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

   ```
   sudo sed -i 's / # deb / deb /' /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
10. In the directory with the unpacked driver run:

    ```
    sudo sh ./ati-installer.sh 15.302 --install
    ```
11. Further installation is in normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

AMD has decided to work on the open source drivers rather than providing proprietry drivers. From Ubuntu 16.04 onwards there is no FGLRX and the AMD drivers will not work.

This means you do not have to install anything. Everything should work fine. If it does not then your going to have to wait for the open source drivers to get up to scratch (AMD is working on those now), or go back to an older release of Ubuntu for the moment.

I am using Xenial 16.04 and AMD RADEON HD 6750. It is all working fine so I am wondering if your 'upgrade' is what broke it. I did a clean install.

Refs:
 http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-16.04-Dropping-fglrx
 https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#fglrx

[edit]
 Steam wont launch on clean install.

```
cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

details here http://www.badbod.com/ubuntu-16-04-xenial-amd-steam/
[/edit]